# Обрезка текста после br

Tags: php

Доброе время суток :). Каким образом можно обрезать текст после `<br>`? Допустим, есть текст:

> Бла-бла-бла <br> Бла-бла.

Как получить из этого только "Бла-бла-бла"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = 'Бла-бла-бла <br> Бла-бла.';
$find   = '<br>';
echo substr ($text, 0, strrpos($text, $find));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно всё нарезать на строки..

```
$res = explode('<br>',$string);
print_R($res);
/**
array(
   [0] => 'Бла-бла-бла',
   [1] => 'Бла бла'
);
*/
```

Answer (score -2):

```
preg_replace(); -- заменяет символы
strip_tags(); -- обрезает html-теги.
```